# Firefox fails to run on New Ubuntu 22.04 Installation

Tags: firefox, snap

The first thing I did after installing Ubuntu 22.04 was install Firefox. Pasted below is the installation command response, followed by the error message when I attempt to run Firefox.

The machine is being run locally. After installing the ZFS file system Ubuntu Studio was installed using the command output:

```
apt install --yes ubuntustudio-desktop
```

After installation I booted, and could not find Firefox. It was not where I expected in the Application launcher. It did not appear where I expected to find it in the "Internet" category. Also the command "which firefox" did not get a result. So I attempted to install it.

Now the Firefox icon is in the Internet category in spite of my having removed it with the "sdo apt remove firefox" command. Also the "which firefox" command still finds it.

Now when I attempt to launch Firefox I get this error:

```
2022/07/03 16:49:54.424008 cmd_run.go:1053: WARNING: cannot start document portal: Expected portal at "/run/user/1000/doc", got "/home/stephen/.cache/doc"
/system.slice/sddm.service is not a snap cgroup
```

Below is an excerpt from the systemd-cgls command:

```
Control group /:
-.slice
├─init.scope 
│ └─1 /sbin/init splash
└─system.slice 
  ├─sddm.service 
  │ ├─ 4155 /usr/bin/sddm
  │ ├─ 4346 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{c2985236-69a5-41fc-bc30-f25>
  │ ├─ 4869 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sddm/sddm-helper --socket /tmp/sddm-auth2e0148a3-75ed-4>
  │ ├─ 4882 /usr/bin/kwalletd5 --pam-login 7 8
```

I have recently discovered:

1. The global variable XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set to anything.
2. There is only one user on this newly installed Ubuntu 22.04 OS. It would be expected the user number for it is 1000. This is verified by the global $UID being set to that number as expected. But the directory /run/user/1000 does not exist. The directory /run/user/ is empty.

pam_systemd is supposed to set XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, and create /run/user/1000. It is failing to for reasons I do not know.

I have made syslog available for download at: https://www.mediafire.com/file/4duykf9u2mgwa23/Target_Computer_syslog_2022-07-16.zip/file .

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

The initial Firefox installation attempt:

```
$ sudo apt --yes install firefox
[sudo] password for stephen: 
Reading package lists.. Done
Building dependency tree.. Done
Reading state information.. Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 72.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 261 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 firefox amd64 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2 [72.3 kB]
Fetched 72.3 kB in 1s (137 kB/s)
Requesting to save current system state
Successfully saved as "autozsys_oaq4s7"
Preconfiguring packages ..
Selecting previously unselected package firefox.
(Reading database .. 251528 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ../firefox_1%3a1snap1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ..
=> Installing the firefox snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the firefox snap
snap "firefox" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
=> Snap installation complete
Unpacking firefox (1:1snap1-0ubuntu2) ..
Setting up firefox (1:1snap1-0ubuntu2) ..
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browse
r (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x
-www-browser) in auto mode
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ..
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ..
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ..
ZSys is adding automatic system snapshot to GRUB menu
stephen@stephen:~$ firefox
/system.slice/ssh.service is not a snap cgroup
```

Comment: The question is unclear because when you install Ubuntu, Firefox is already there. So why did you have to install it?

Comment: You installed the *deb* wrapper that causes the *snap* package to attempt to install; the snap package however was already installed as is seen in this message from your paste - "*snap "firefox" is already installed*" thus nothing was done except for installing a *wrapper*, wasting some disk space, altered/complicated package database. The *snap* package is slower to start on initial run (*first time that session/boot*) so have you waited awhile?  Your prompt didn't return to wait for next command, thus it looks like it was still running. Are you using the machine locally?

Comment: I edited my question to answer your questions, and clarify things. Some of actions I did were done by remote SSH on another computer a few feet away so I can copy, and paste, commands from documentation about how to do things. It is necessary because I do not yet have a functioning browser on the on the new computer I have this difficulty with.

Comment: I think your problem is not that much with firefox, but with `sddm` or the interference between them. Do you really use `sddm` intentionally?

Comment: It is Firefox that seems to use sddm. Its usage is a decision Firefox developers would have made. I was not aware of sddm's existence until this error.

Comment: I have more information about this problem that I have edited into the question.

Comment: `firefox` and `sddm` are unrelated.   Ubuntu Studio uses KDE, a Qt5 desktop that uses `sddm` by default; where as Ubuntu 22.04 LTS uses GNOME & `gdm3`, You introduced `sddm` to your box by the addition of Ubuntu Studio Desktop with the --yes option.

Answer (score 0):

I have firefox working. To get it to work I had to disable cgroup. To do this I followed Tim Richardson's instructions at c25.

When launched it output many permission denied errors which are attached. How I fixed these I describe in this thread:
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=3097766

Comment: Why didn't you just install Ubuntu Studio in the first place? https://ubuntustudio.org/